# Anonymous PHP function with in_array not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have this simple array `$tree` in PHP that I need to filter based on an array of tags matching those in the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Introduction
            [id] => 798162f0-d779-46b6-96cb-ede246bf4f3f
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => client corp
                    [1] => version 2
                )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Chapter one
            [id] => 761e1909-34b3-4733-aab6-ebef26d3fcb9
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => pro feature
                )
        )
)
```

I tried using an anonymous function like so:

```
$selectedTree = array_filter($tree, function($array) use ($selectedTags){
   return in_array($array->tags, $selectedTags, true);
});
```

$selectedTags:

```
Array
(
    [0] => client corp
)
```

The above is returning empty when I'd expect item 1 to be returned. No error thrown. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a bit unclear what the current behavior is. Is it not working? Is it not filtering it correctly? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: @ChrisForrence sorry, it's not filtering (i.e. returning empty). No error thrown.

Comment: Your function is searching for `$selectedTags` in `$array->tags`, both of which are arrays. `in_array()` will only return true if the arrays match exactly (same number of elements with the same content). You need to loop through one array, searching for each element in the other array in turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of [in_array($neddle, $haystack)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). the `$neddle` must need to be a `String`, but you're giving an array that is why its not behaving properly.

But if you like to pass array as value of `$selectedTags` then you might try something like below:

```
$selectedTree = array_filter($tree, function($array) use ($selectedTags){
   return count(array_intersect($array->tags, $selectedTags)) > 0;
});
```

Ref: [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading the question correctly, you need to look at each object in `$tree` array and see if the tags property contains any of the the elements in  `$selectedTags`

Here is a procedural way to do it.

```
$filtered = array();
foreach ($tree as $key => $obj) {
    $commonElements = array_intersect($selectedTags, $obj->tags);
    if (count($commonElements) > 0) {
        $filtered[$key] = $obj;
    }
}
```

I was going to also post the functional way of doing this but, see thecodeparadox's answer for that implementation.